# Loop over half-yearly dates

Tags: loops, date, stata

I am running an event study in Stata and I would like to interact each of my dates with a dummy variable. The dates are divided into semesterd, i.e., half years, `%th` format.

Here below what I tried:

```
foreach yh = yh(1933h1)(1)yh(1958h2){
gen d_`yh'=dummy*(sdate==`yh')
label var d_`yh' "`yh'"
}
```

Do you have any idea of how I could proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
forval yh = `= yh(1933, 1)'/`= yh(1958, 2)' {
    local YH : subinstr local yh "-" "_", all 
    gen d_`YH' = dummy*(sdate==`yh')
    label var d_`YH' "`yh'"
}
```

or

```
forval yh = -58/-3 {
    local YH : subinstr local yh "-" "_", all 
    gen d_`YH' = dummy*(sdate==`yh')
    label var d_`YH' "`yh'"
}
```

The errors in your code are

1. Confusing `foreach` with `forvalues`.
2. Either loop expects to see constants here determining the limits. You can evaluate an expression on the fly, but not as you tried to do it.
3. Calls like `yh(1933h1)` are wrong. `yh` requires two numeric arguments separated by a comma.
4. The half-yearly dates you are looping over are all negative, as occurring before 1960. But minus signs can't be part of variable names.